# Shell that automatically trims spaces for no reason

Tags: bash, shell, echo, zsh, double-quotes

##### Introduction

I was trying to do some instructions on a file line by line with:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
done < file
```

When I noticed that there was a problem with trailing whitespaces (for example: `"    a     "` => `"a"`) that were automatically deleted, which is a real problem for me.

I searched in the documentation and didn't find any mention of that. And there is the same problem with printf.

##### Minimal example:

```bash
touch example # Create a file
echo "  exa    mple    " >> example # Add some text
cat example #    exa    mple    
echo $(cat example) # exa mple
rm example # Delete the file
```

In this example, I don't understand why `echo $(cat example)`  doesn't have some trailing whitespaces.

And this "problem" is also here with:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo $line # exa mple
done < example
```

##### Version:

Tested with:

- `zsh v5.9`
- `bash v5.2.2`

Comment: Remove `IFS=` from `IFS= read -r line` to allow leading/trailing spaces and tabs to be removed. With `IFS=`, you're specifying "there are no word splitting characters" which allows the line to be captured verbatim. The unquoted `echo $(cat example)` allows word splitting to occur.

Comment: @glennjackman Are you sure for the `IFS=` ? If yes can you provide a code example that works? I tested your suggestion on the problem that I mentioned and didn't notice any differences

Comment: The result of unquoted `$(cat example)` is subject to word splitting. Try with `echo "$(cat example)"`. But this is "Useless Use of echo"

Comment: Oh @M.NejatAydin looks like you're right ok!

Comment: @TKirishima, I lost track of whether or no you want to keep the whitespace. Socowi answers your question. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: The `echo $(cat example)` (which can be written simpler as `echo $(<example)` shows this behaviour of course only for _bash_, not _zsh_. If you want the spaces to be "squeezed" in zsh as well, do a `tr -s ' ' example` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IFS= read -r line < file` is correctly reading unmodified lines *with* leading and trailing spaces. You can confirm this by printing the variable using `declare -p line`.

**But** after you read the lines correctly, you are mangling them during your print commands. Both `echo $(cat example)` and `echo $line` have unquoted expansions, which cause the shell to word-split your lines.

Quote them to resolve the problem:

```
echo "$(cat example)"
echo "$line"
```

By the way, https://shellcheck.net/ is excellent for spotting and explaining errors like these.